DEM update/interpolation algorithm from control points
Context: I have a reference DEM, and Icesat-2 points covering some parts of it. The DEM is from 2012 and the Icesat-2 points range from 2018 to 2023.
Goal: I am looking for a way to 'update' the reference DEM from the Icesat-2 measurement, where the update fits exactly the measurement points and the rest is fitted from the reference DEM, and impacted by the points around (all weighted by distance).
Example: If all the measurements show the surface is 2m lower in 2018, then the entirety of the DEM is lowered by 2m.
Problem: In reality the measurements are all giving slighlty different values, and when the algorithm considers a point with no measurements, it should modify its value from the reference DEM, to be impacted by measured points around (weighted by distance for example).
Do you know what could help me do this ?
I already looked at Krieging, Gaussian Process Regression, Weighted Neighbors and others, but when they interpolate points without measurements, they have no knowledge of the reference DEM (thus we end up just interpolating between the measurements rather than from the ref DEM fitted to the measurements).

Interpolate difference and add result to existing DEM

I'll try it, thanks
